# What are the limitations of images in Facebook Messenger's Generic Templates?

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Some images of mine, for example https://www.honda.co.th/th/jazz/assets/img/gallery/exterior/ext-05.jpg,
 are not shown and I can't find the limitations in API documents.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the documentation here : [Generic Template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template)
As far as i understand the problem might be the ratio as it clearly documented:

> horizontal image aspect ratio is 1.91:1 and square image aspect ratio is 1:1